# Undeclared variable from base class when derived class has property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have the following code below, where a base class has a member which is (should be) accessible by a derived class.

The code below however gives a compilation error 
`...abcAppDelegate.m:30: error: 'baseVal_' undeclared (first use in this function)`

If I call the variable using `self->baseVal_` or if I remove the property defined in the derived class then everything is ok.

Also, if I define a category of the derived class, then I can access baseVal_ without error.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------
// BASE CLASS
//---------------------------------------------------------------

@interface BaseClass : NSObject 
{
@protected    
    BOOL baseVal_;
} 
@end

@implementation BaseClass 
@end

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// DERIVED CLASS
//---------------------------------------------------------------

@interface DerivedClass : BaseClass {
} 
@property (readwrite) BOOL val;
@end

@implementation DerivedClass
@synthesize val;
- (void) foo {
    baseVal_ = YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting the error in your App Delegate, not the DerivedClass.  Can you post the AppDelegate code where you are accessing this variable?

Comment: just for the example here I have stuck the classes (the exact code as above) into the appDelegate.m file - but the example is taken from a larger codebase

Comment: BTW:  Objective-C doesn't have member variables, but instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778405/not-so-silly-objective-c-inheritance-problem-when-using-property-gcc-bug). Seems to possibly be a bug with GCC, but it's easily fixable by adding `val` as an instance variable instead of using the property without.

Comment: Is is solvable by either adding the member for the property or accessing it using self->val

Comment: A better solution is to switch to LLVM.